# php preg split data

Tags: php, regex

I want to split text by sections and the names of the sections that are inside of === === So data is like

```
   ===A=== 
   a
   ===B=== 
   b
   ===C=== 
   c
```

preg split is like:

```
  $sections = preg_split('/===([^=]+)===(?!=)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but if the data are like

```
   ===A=== 
   a
   ====0==== 
   0
   ===B=== 
   b
   ===C=== 
   c
```

It gets wrong (i need to split it only by sections with 3x === and ignore the other parts) that's why there is the negative look behind.

**Edit**: it turned out that problem was that split took last === from the ====0==== and made new fake section name until first === of ===B=== so it made from

```
 ====0==== 
   0
 ===B===
```

new fake section like this (cutting away what is in parenthesis)

```
 (====0=)===
 0
 ===(B===)
```

Comment: please show how your desired output should look like

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('/^===([^=]*)===((?:\R(?!=).*)*)/m', $s,$matches)`

Comment: @CodeManiac output is an single dimension array of splited data with like 'captured section name', 'section data'. so like first is empty ['', 'A', 'a ====0==== 0', 'B', 'b' ... ] that's how it should be

Comment: You seemed surprised that the split function makes elements out of what it doesn't match. That's what split does... and, in %99.99 of the cases, split is only for the simplest of atomic jobs. Not in anyway intended for what you want to use it for .

Comment: @sln it works fine for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach (although my regex is rusty) would be

```
preg_match_all("/(?:\s|^)===(\w*)===\s/", $input, $sections);
```

So just `(?:\s|^)===(\w*)===\s` which is whitespace or start of document, ==='s text and then ==='s and finally whitespace.

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ===A===

    [1] =>  ===B===

    [2] =>  ===C===

)
```

Using...

```
$sections = preg_split("/(?:\s|^)===(\w*)===\s/", $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] =>           a
          ====0====
          0

    [2] => B
    [3] =>           b

    [4] => C
    [5] =>           c
)
```

Comment: yes problem was i see, that it took last = from the ====0==== and made new section name across the next line to ===B so it needed somehow tied to to new lines constraints also.. you did the job thanks. it should work i guess

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using `prep_match_all`, with the following regex pattern:

```
(?!<=)={3,}[^=]+={3}(?!=).*?(?=[^=]={3}[^=]+={3}[^=]|$)
```

This pattern says to match a section header, being defined by three `=` with some other character(s) in the middle, followed by all content until reaching either another section header *or* the end of the entire input.

```
$input = "===A=== 
          a
          ====0==== 
          0
          ===B=== 
          b
          ===C=== 
          c";
preg_match_all("/(?!<=)={3,}[^=]+={3}(?!=).*?(?=[^=]={3}[^=]+={3}[^=]|$)/s", $input, $sections);
print_r($sections[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ===A=== 
   a
   ====0==== 
   0

    [1] => ===B=== 
   b

    [2] => ===C=== 
   c
)
```

Note that we use the `/s` modified in the PHP regex pattern for dot all mode.  This ensures that the `.*` used in the pattern matches across newlines.

Comment: hi thx for fast answer but it should be [0] ===A=== a ====0==== 0. ignore more than 3x and treat it as section data. and what about use preg split?

Comment: @luky Sorry, I guess I misread your question, perhaps because you never showed us the output you want.  I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: yes i didnt explain it well, sorry. cool, but could you make working the preg split? that would be best :)

Comment: I wouldn't use `preg_split` for this, because your goal is to capture all content.  Splitting generally means _consuming_ (read: removing) some of the content in your input, that is, unless you completely split using lookarounds, which might be difficult to phrase here.  So, I will stay with the `preg_match_all` solution.

Comment: yes thanks for the fast help anyway. problem was that it captured the 3x = between lines how i said below.